# Problem inicializacting native SDK on Flutter: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.Object

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk, tuya

I am trying to integrate an SDK from the company TUYA (Smart Life App SDK) into a Flutter project as a native SDK using Java.
I followed the steps that are posted on the [official website](https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/app-development/integrated?id=Ka69nt96cw0uj), with some adaptations to make it work in a Flutter project. When all the integration is done, build of the app is ok and I try to Initialize the SDK it shows a FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

E/AndroidRuntime(12996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12996): Process: com.example.project, PID: 12996
E/AndroidRuntime(12996): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.Object com.tuya.smart.security.jni.SecureNativeApi.doCommandNative(android.content.Context, int, byte[], byte[], boolean, boolean) (tried Java_com_tuya_smart_security_jni_SecureNativeApi_doCommandNative and Java_com_tuya_smart_security_jni_SecureNativeApi_doCommandNative__Landroid_content_Context_2I_3B_3BZZ)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.smart.security.jni.SecureNativeApi.doCommandNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.smart.security.jni.JNICLibrary.doCommandNative(JNICLibrary.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.sdk.network.TuyaNetworkSecurity.initJNI(TuyaNetworkSecurity.java:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.smart.android.network.TuyaSmartNetWork.initialize(TuyaSmartNetWork.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.smart.sdk.TuyaSdk.initTuyaData(TuyaSdk.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.smart.sdk.TuyaSdk.init(TuyaSdk.java:220)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.smart.sdk.TuyaSdk.init(TuyaSdk.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.tuya.smart.home.sdk.TuyaHomeSdk.init(TuyaHomeSdk.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.example.project.FTuyaSmartApp.onCreate(FTuyaSmartApp.java:14)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1211)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6725)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(12996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

If anyone has had a similar problem, please let me know, because I really don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Tuya Smart Life SDK doesn't work on x86 android, as they call platform specific native libraries that they don't package for x86.

From the fast integration document:

> App SDK v3.10.0 and earlier only support armeabi-v7a. App SDK v3.11.0 and later have integrated armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a. If you have added .so libraries to the project, you must remove them and only use the library included in the SDK.

<s>So you'll need to set up an emulated ARM device in AVD manager using an arm64 image.</s>

However, note the normal QEMU2 based emulator only runs ARM images where the API < 27 (i.e. nougat), and *very* slowly.

Thankfully - Google have added partial arm emulation (i.e. most of the OS runs under x86, but apps compiled for arm run under emulation) to x86_64 versions >= 11. [Source: Google blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html)

Tested it out, and the Tuya API works OK on Android 11.0 x86_64.

Getting flutter to build for arm rather than x86_64 as part of regular tooling is harder - I've only tried manually forcing it so far:

```
flutter build apk --debug --split-per-abi
adb -e install .\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really useful. I try to run it on a physical device and it work

Comment: Yes it's a lot easier on a physical device, especially as you can use bluetooth.